# event.stopPropagation Not Working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, stoppropagation

I am building a sidebar vertical menu that contains Main Menu items and one level of sub-menu items.

I am using Javascript and CSS so that when the user clicks a top-level menu item, its sub-menu items will toggle their visibility - i.e. Click a main item and its sub items will appear. Click the main item again and the sub items disappear.

To avoid the sub-menu from toggling when the user clicks a sub-menu item, I used the event.stopPropagation() method.

The desired result works in Chrome, Safari, and Dolphin, but does not work in Firefox 26.0 nor Android Firefox 26.0.1.

If you run [this example (JSBin)](http://jsbin.com/OyUvUqa/1/), you will notice that you can click `Menu 2` and/or `Menu 3` and a sub-menu will be displayed. That part is fine in all browsers.

However, if you click a sub-menu item (i.e. Menu 3.1) in Firefox, the sub-menu will disappear - which is not the desired effect I want. If you click a sub-menu item in Chrome/Safari, the sub-menu stays visible - which is what I want to occur.

I read on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/event.stopPropagation#Syntax) that the event.stopPropagation() is supported in `Chrome`, `Firefox (Gecko)`, `IE9`, `Opera`, and `Safari (WebKit)`. So, I'm confused as to why the stopProp method is not working in my case.

Can you take a look at my JS example and tell me what's up?

Here's the Javascript that I'm running ([also at JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/OyUvUqa/1/)):

```
function goTo(id) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     location.href = id;
 }

 function toggleChildDisplay(parentElement) {
     var children = parentElement.children;
     var displayStyle = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
         displayStyle = children[i].style.display;
         if (displayStyle.toLowerCase() === "none" || displayStyle === "") 
             children[i].style.display = "list-item";
         else 
             children[i].style.display = "none";
     }
}
```

... and here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="level1">
    <li onclick="toggleChildDisplay(this)">Menu 1</li>
    <li onclick="toggleChildDisplay(this)">Menu 2
        <ul class="level2">
            <li onclick="goTo('#')">Menu 2.1</li>
            <li onclick="goTo('#')">Menu 2.2</li>
            <li onclick="goTo('#')">Menu 2.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li onclick="toggleChildDisplay(this)">Menu 3
        <ul class="level2">
            <li onclick="goTo('#')">Menu 3.1</li>
            <li onclick="goTo('#')">Menu 3.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*P.S. The environment that I'm developing on will not allow me to use jQuery.*

Comment: Chrome seems to always say that you should use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `event.stopPropagation()`...  Probably not your problem but maybe try it anyways?

Comment: I've already tried the preventDefault(). Still no love there.

Comment: Hm. sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();` --- what is `event` here? I don't see any variable with such name defined.

Comment: @zerkms good point. He's probably referring to `window.event`, that could be a good thing to know

Comment: @zerkms - In my example, the event is from an onclick that exists within a sub-menu li tag. I'll update the OG post to show the HTML.

Comment: Not good. You should be using event handlers on JavaScript to capture the event object, instead of appending onclick attributes on the HTML tags.

Comment: @Jed: "the event is from an onclick" --- how that variable appears magically?

Comment: @zerkms I think OP is using the old IE approach.

Comment: @EfrainReyes: no wondering it doesn't work :-D

Comment: @zerkms - "how that variable appears magically?" - You don't believe in magic! :) .. Good point, though. I followed the syntax on the Moz Dev Network and since my script worked with Chrome and Dolphin, I assumed I was doing it correctly. But now that you have me thinking, I'll pass the onclick event to the goTo() function. Thanks.

Comment: @Jed: MDN page explains `stopPropagation` method of an object of an event type. But it doesn't say there is a variable with `event` name is available globally. Compare to https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/dispatchEvent.html

Comment: @zerkms: Understood. Now that I'm aware of my foolish ways, I am now confused how Chrome/Dolphin magically knew what to do without me specifying the event.

Comment: if you want to learn more about your problem read my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the event as an argument to your function.

```
goTo(event, '#')
```

Then you can do `event.stopPropagation()` and it knows what event is.

http://jsbin.com/OyUvUqa/2

Comment: ... or just use proper event listeners

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript now..**

*inline javascript is not a proper way to write code*

This example shows a 'innovative' solution to handle a menu.

it also shows you how to correctly handle the event and the event's target.

It uses:

1. classList
2. dataset
3. one handler for multiple elements.
4. css to display and hide thee elements.

---

```
function handler(e){
 e=e||window.event;
 var target=e.target||e.srcElement;
 var action=target.dataset['action']||'no action';
 !(action=='toggle')||(target.childNodes[1].classList.toggle('show'));
 !target.dataset['url']||alert(target.dataset['url']);
}
var firstUL=document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
firstUL.addEventListener('click',handler,false);
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/Jj6FY/1/

the boring stuff is that you need to find the various elements with getEl...

but at the end you have more control over everything.

and here is a accordion function.

http://jsfiddle.net/YjCbM/1/

if you have any questions just ask.